# How to install ProtonVpn on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, proxy, ubuntu-20.04

#### The initial steps of installation

**1. Get the DEB setup package for the ProtonVPN repository**

[Download the ProtonVPN DEB package](https://protonvpn.com/download/protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb)

**2. Install the ProtonVPN repo**

**Double-click** downloaded DEB package to install the repo using your default package manager.

**3. Update the apt-get package list** 
`$ sudo apt-get update`

**4. Install the ProtonVPN Linux app** 
`$ sudo apt-get install protonvpn`

---

> It should be noted that from step 2 onwards, typing the sudo apt update command does not update the program repositories, although this problem persists for other similar programs.

> Code error step 3 : 
> Failed to fetch https://protonvpn.com/download/protonvpn-stable-release_1.0.1-1_all.deb/dists/focal/InRelease  Could not connect to protonvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection timed out

> Code error step 4 : 
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package protonvpn

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.